# Drive letter lost after unplug

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, drive-letter

I have to manually assign drive letter whenever I connect my WD Element to my PC (W10). The external hdd has 2 partitions (FAT32 + NTFS) and I have to do this for both of them.  Is there any way to force Windows to assign drive letter for me automatically, or assign letters permanently to the drive? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have more than one of these external drives attached? They sometimes ship with identical UUID in the partition table, which may cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Something is preventing the drives from getting their drive letter automatically. Try assigning drive letters you've **never** used before and see if that helps.